# CSS code for popup so users can still interact with the site

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, popup

I am using Popup Builder plugin on my WordPress website, and you can add your own custom CSS code to a Popup.  I have a banner pop up displayed at the side, the user cant interact with the content on the site whilst the banner is there, they need to either - click the banner to follow the link, close the banner with the 'x' or click away from the banner for it to disappear.

I want the banner to be allowed to remain displayed and the user to be able to interact and click on links on the site and the banner to remain with some custom CSS code.  Can anyone help?

I have tried some code but I am not experienced, it isnt working.

Comment: Welcome to SO, I recommend checking out [mcve] and [ask].